# phing input task within if strange behaviour

Tags: phing

I'm encountering the following:

```
<target name="test_something">
    <if>
        <equals arg1="1" arg2="1" />
        <then>
            <input propertyname="confirm_cleanup" defaultValue="y" validArgs="y,n" promptChar="?">Hello</input>
        </then>
    </if>
</target>
```

When I run the task, the output is: HelloHelloHelloHello(y,n) [y]?

Any ideas why it is echoed 4 times?

Cheers

Comment: Is that your full build file?

Comment: No, it's wrapped within a <project> with <?xml?> header.

Comment: I have encountered this exact issue - an input task within a <then> block gets printed 4 times. 
It doesn't help to put the prompt text in the message attribute either, so it must be a bug with Phing.

Comment: A ticket has been just opened scheduled to be fixed in 2.5.0 version http://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/1006

Comment: I opened that ticket and unfortunately the "Version" refers to the version that has the bug, rather than "Milestone", which would be when it is intended to be fixed. I'll keep an eye on it and update this if there is any progress.